# Can a modern compiler optimize x - y > 0 to x > y?

Tags: compare, compiler-optimization

I was discussing some code with friends and this concept came up. None of us have taken compilers yet, and we assumed that `x > y` would execute faster. But then I started to wonder if a compiler would just end up optimizing `x - y > 0` anyway (or actually, since we were discussing Python code, the interpreter).

My understanding is that, unoptimized, `x - y > 0` would take longer to calculate than `x > y` because of the extra arithmetic step, but I would imagine that the two expressions are functionally equivalent.

Comment: Depends on the language and the implementation. CPython won't do it, and a language with guaranteed wrap-on-overflow won't do it unless the implementation can prove there's no overflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of factors that need to be considered when deciding whether to translate `x - y > 0` into `x > y`. First, `x > y` is not necessarily faster than `x - y > 0`. In many processor architectures `x > y` is implemented by computing `x - y` and checking the processor status flags, i.e. `x > y` and `x - y > 0` are equally fast.  Second to be able to do perform a transformation the expressions before and after must be equivalent and, depending on the semantics regarding over- and under-flow, this is not necessarily the case for the two expressions.

For instance in C the transformation is valid for signed types as over- and under-flow of signed expressions are considered undefined behaviour, i.e. if it happens the whole program is flawed and anything goes. This means that for all valid programs the expressions are equivalent and the transformation can be applied. For unsigned types, on the hand, all expessions wrap into the domain of the type. This implies that `x - y > 0` is trivially true while `x > y` is not, thus it is not a valid transformation.